# How conditionally change to a new storyboard

Tags: objective-c, button, segue, ios9, xcode7

i'm writing a little IOS app using Xcode 7 IOS 9 (objective-c). Right now I'm trying to switch from the main storyboard to the second storyboard by pressing a button called "confirm". How can i write code in ViewController.m to conditionally go to the second storyboard? So if all input is correct, user presses confirm it will go to the new storyboard, else stay and display warning message. Thank you!

Comment: can you please post code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
    if (yourcondition)
           storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryBoard1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    else
            storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryBoard2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    YourTargetViewController *targetCon = [stryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TargetControllerID"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetCon animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked! I have a follow up question tho, if you can help me. So I have three textfields where the user enter their info, if the info format is not correct i will display a warning message in red color, then let them type in the new info. I tried to use a while loop to wait for their new info then go through the same if statements, if their new info is correct then switch to another storyboard. It didn't work for some reason. Can you tell me what I can do to display the warning message then wait for new input?

Comment: Its good to raise another question on SF by posting the code which you have implemented till now..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. May be help you.

```
//button Actions
- (IBAction)loginbtnClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.tfEmail resignFirstResponder];
    [self.tfPasswrd resignFirstResponder];
    if ([self.tfEmail.text isEqualToString:@""] || [self.tfPasswrd.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
          UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@“Title” message:@"You are required to fill out all fields." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
          [alert show];
          return;
    }
   if ([self isEmailValid:self.tfEmail.text])
   {
         //put your required code here.

        //Navigate to next view controller.
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main” bundle:nil];
        HomeVC *homeVC =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVCID"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatVC animated:TRUE];
   }
   else
   {
         UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@“Title” message:@"Please enter valid email address." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
   }
}
```